# Can't figure out how to edit this bootstrap CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a beginner with CSS and Bootstrap and am having trouble changing the  bootstrap css so that I can center the text in my navbar. I am working on a navbar for a website that turns into the caret symbol when the screen size is reduced.

I've spent well over an hour trying to find which class/attributes I should change but to no avail. I found that when I change ".navbar-collapse" and add "text-align: center", it changes the text to be in the center, but its only when the screen size is small. I do not know how to center it when the screen size is bigger than "navbar-expand-sm".

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
     <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_target">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse_target">
         <span class="navbar-text">madlee</span>
         <ul class="navbar-nav">
             <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                 <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="dropdown_target" href="#">
                     Work History
                     <span class="caret"></span>
                 </a>
                 <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-target">
                     <div class="dropdown-divider" href="#"></div>
                 </div>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resume</a>
             </li>

         </ul>
     </div>
 </nav>
```

I have been trying to get all the text in the navbar to be in the center of the screen instead of on the left.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you gone through these [Bootstrap tutorials](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/)? They have a well-shaped and maintained documentation. But if you don't want to go there, lets clear some points here.

- Your code is perfectly correct, no errors.
- You need a little bit of CSS knowledge, just add three lines of code for this to work. And here it is:

```css
ul {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_target">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse_target">
    <span class="navbar-text">madlee</span>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="dropdown_target" href="#">
                     Work History
                     <span class="caret"></span>
                 </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-target">
          <div class="dropdown-divider" href="#"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resume</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**edited**

The above code will work but there are various ways to achieve this. I have just stated an obvious one. And yes important will help in overriding any other CSS implied on it.

You might want to go for a CSS quickie here: [Link](https://learnlayout.com/)

Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding additional styles in your main navbar

```
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your css file and add this line

```
ul { margin: auto !important;}
```